Decryption failed for JWT token - ASP.NET Core
My jwedecrypt code shown below throws this error:

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDecryptionFailedException: 'IDX10609: Decryption failed. No Keys tried: token: '[Security Artifact of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.SecurityArtifact' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/SecurityArtifactLogging.]'.'

My code:
public void ValidateJweToken(string token, RSA publicKey, RSA privateKey)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // Here we set the decryption key to the private key
        TokenDecryptionKey = new RsaSecurityKey(privateKey),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, // For JWT verification
        IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(publicKey), // Use public key for verification
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true
    };
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    SecurityToken validatedToken;
    try
    {
        // Decrypt and validate the token
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        // Token is valid; proceed with your logic
    }
    catch (SecurityTokenDecryptionFailedException ex)
    {
        // Log or handle the decryption failure
        Console.WriteLine($"Decryption failed: {ex.Message}");
    }
    catch (SecurityTokenValidationException ex)
    {
        // Log or handle validation failure
        Console.WriteLine($"Token validation failed: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


could you please share how you are generating or using the RSA keys? could you try to install and use System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt package. Could you check if the RSA key is valid or not? is it possible for you to share reproducible sample so that we can help you
